# How to create a Lock / Unlocked checkbox for WPF

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles

I've got the following style

```
<Style x:Key="LockBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <!-- Locked -->
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#x1f512;" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <!-- Unlocked -->
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#x1f513;" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This sets a unicode lock / unlock symbols as the checkbox content. However
I'd like to put the lock / unlock symbols where the image is. How to
do this?

Comment: "where the image is" - which image are you talking about? the actual check mark? If so you'll need to edit the `CheckBox` template and that part of the control would be a `ToggleButton` and you'll need to set the `Content` of it there accordingly.

Comment: I think he wants the checkmark to be replaced with the lock/unlocked icon. To reach this goal you would have to edit the CheckBox ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Viv Actually you are right, I ended up just using a toggle button and using a Style trigger on the content. Still for the specific question I asked the answer by steven is quite usefull as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete example of a ControlTemplate you could use to reach your goal.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
            Width="24" Height="24"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="&#x1f512;" Name="LockedIcon" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <TextBlock Text="&#x1f513;" Name="UnlockedIcon" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Grid>
        <Border 
            x:Name="WhiteSpaceBorder"
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
            Width="8" 
            Visibility="Visible"/>
        <ContentPresenter 
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
            TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <!-- Locked -->
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LockedIcon" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <!-- Unlocked -->
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UnlockedIcon" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WhiteSpaceBorder" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: even in this case I'd rather the `ControlTemplate` `Trigger` modify the `Text` of the `TextBlock` than use 2 separate `TextBlock`'s and toggle visibility. One because that way you only need 1 `Trigger`. Second because it gives you some extensibility, If you have a Tri-State in the future you do not need to add another `Visibility` Toggle on older `Trigger`'s and backtrack but just set the `Text` accordingly. Finally the lesser xaml elements the better. No point in having a mutually exclusive `TextBlock` here when triggers achieve it fine...just my opinion tho.